# How to share ServiceProvider in Maui Blazor for Maui services and Blazor services

Tags: c#, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I am trying to figure out how to share the services between Maui and Blazor in a MauiBlazor project.
The goal is to be able to consume the same singletons without having a static instance of these singletons stored somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it may be a more convenient way in the future releases, I found a way to do that with some inspirations from [Maui.Plugins.PageResolver](https://github.com/matt-goldman/Maui.Plugins.PageResolver). Related to the issue [maui#792](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/792)

I have added a [nuget + working sample app on Github](https://github.com/JeanCollas/MauiBlazorDependencyInjection)

Here is how I solved it:

**1. Create a repository for the service provider**

```
public static class Resolver
{
    private static IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider => _serviceProvider ?? throw new Exception("Service provider has not been initialized");

    /// <summary>
    /// Register the service provider
    /// </summary>
    public static void RegisterServiceProvider(IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        _serviceProvider = sp;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get service of type <typeparamref name="T"/> from the service provider.
    /// </summary>
    public static T Resolve<T>() where T : class
        => ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();
}
```

**2. An extension method for the app startup**

```
public static void UseResolver(this MauiApp app)
{
    Resolver.RegisterServiceProvider(app.Services);
}
```

Or to avoid dependency to Maui:

```
public static void UseResolver(this IServiceProvider sp)
{
    Resolver.RegisterServiceProvider(sp);
}
```

**3a. A sample test service**

```
public class TestSingletonService
{
    private static int _staticIndex = 0;
    public int Index {  get; set; }

    public TestSingletonService()
    {
        Index = _staticIndex++;
    }
}
```

**3b. Register the service collection**

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .RegisterBlazorMauiWebView()
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            });

        builder.Services.AddBlazorWebView();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

        // Register any other service / ViewModel / Page here
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<TestSingletonService>();

        // Pre-build the app
        var app = builder.Build();
        // Intercept and register the ServiceProvider
        app.UseResolver();
        // Or to avoid Maui dependency
        // app.Services.UseResolver();
        // Return the app as usual
        return app;
    }
}
```

**4a. Use it as your factory from Maui side**

```cs
Resolver.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TestSingletonService>();
Console.WriteLine($"Instance number {TestSingletonService.Index}");
```

**4b. The services instances will be shared with your Blazor `@inject` services.**

```
@inject TestSingletonService tester
Instance number @(tester.Index).
```